# I currently have L2 visa , am I eligible to complete my CPL program in USA

Tags: commercial-aviation

I am from India, I currently hold dependent L2 visa , can I complete CPL program (commerical pilot licence) in USA

Comment: I think this is a better question for Law SE.  Specifically immigration law.  *(AFAIK visas for training and education are not aviation specific)*